# If the function $f(x) =\lfloor \frac{(x-2)^3}{a}\rfloor \sin(x-2) +a\cos(x-2), \lfloor . \rfloor$ denotes .....

Tags: calculus, continuity

Problem :

If the function $$f(x) =\left\lfloor \frac{(x-2)^3}{a} \right\rfloor \sin(x-2) + a \cos(x-2),$$ where $\lfloor . \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function is continuous and differentiable in $[4,6]$ then (options are)

(a) $a\in [8,64]$

(b) $a\in (0,8]$

(c)  $a\in [64, \infty)$

What I understood is the function is continuous if the part $\lfloor \frac{(x-2)^3}{a} \rfloor = 0$, is it correct but with the help of this how can we find the range of $a$. please suggest thanks...

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{(x-2)^{3}}{a}\in [0,1)\ \ \forall x\in[4,6]$, so $a>64$.
So option (c) is the correct answer