# Find all possible values of $a$ if $f(x) = \lfloor {\frac{(x-2)^3}{a}} \rfloor + a \cdot \cos(x - 2)$ is continuous in $[4, 6]$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

> Find all possible values of $a$ if $$f(x) = \bigg\lfloor {\frac{(x-2)^3}{a}} \bigg \rfloor + a \cdot \cos(x - 2)$$ is continuous in $[4, 6]$.

Hello, I think the answer to this problem is $\boxed{a \in (-\infty, -64] \cup (64, \infty)}$.

We figure out possible points of discontinuity in $f(x)$ and try to make them continuous. Note that $a \cdot \cos(x-2)$ is continuous, so it does not contribute.

This function can be discontinuous when $\frac{(x-2)^3}{a}$ is integer. Since $(x-2)^3 \in [8, 64]$, $|a| > 64$ guarantees that this can never be integer. When $|a| < 64$, there will be necessarily some $x \in [4, 6]$ that will cause it to become integer, and hence discontinuous.

Finally, note that $|a| = 64$, should be checked with boundary points. The boundary point $x = 4$ is continuous, but for $x = 6$, if $a = 64$, the left hand limit will not be the same. This does not seem to be a problem with $a = -64$ though. So, my answer = $\boxed{a \in (-\infty, -64] \cup (64, \infty)}$.

Is my work correct?

PS: This question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653027/if-the-function-fx-lfloor-fracx-23a-rfloor-sinx-2-a-cosx-2) but it doesn't answer my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[.]$ denote GIF, then
for $a>64 , [(x-2)^3/a]=0 \text{in} x\in[4,6]$ then $f(x)=a \cos (x-2)$ which is continuous for all real values of $x$. So the answer is $a>64$.

Comment: Why shouldn't $a < -64$ e.g $a = -100$ be included?